# in Laravel Project, Can't find api urls

Tags: php, laravel, rest

404 not found error is sending to new post api urls.
I used these commands

```
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

But problem not solved. what should I do ?
?

Comment: try php artisan route:clear and then php artisan route:list

Answer (score 1):

Use this commmand to list all routes project

```
php artisan route:list
```

Comment: API Urls is not found in route:list. But I write correct url's.

Answer (score 0):

Add API urls to `routes/api.php` then try this that may help:

```
php artisan optimize:clear
php artisan route:list
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Route

Route Default Rule's

```
**API** 
{url}/api/{xyz}
**WEB**
{url}/{xyz}
```

Also, Try to Use

```
php artisan route:clear
```